# Talk to Agilent 33220A using VB in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, interface, instrumentation

I am learning VB (using VS 2012) in order to interface with Agilent 33220A function generator (has USB, GPIB and LAN interfaces available) via USB or GPIB.

I am well versed in Matlab but am a beginner in VB and instrument control and interfacing with a PC.

Please could someone direct me to some relevant examples for me to get started?

Ideally, I would like to have examples dealing with Agilent 33220A.

The final aim is to add an additional functionality (of Agilent 33220A) to a code already written in VB (in VS 2012).

Thanks.

Comment: This is probably off-topic for this site. You cna probably do a little research on your own for a start ("Agilent 33220A visual basic" as a web search?) and then take a stab at it and come back when you have a specific coding question.

Comment: Please don't tag with [tag:vba] questions that have nothing to do with VBA. VBA code isn't written with Visual Studio.

Comment: FWIW questions asking for tutorials, examples, or other off-site resources are explicitly off-topic; see [ask].

Comment: Very easy to interface. Get hold of the protocol which is ASCII based, and follow the examples provided.

Answer (score 0):

Here are all the examples provided by Keysight:

https://www.keysight.com/main/techSupport.jspx?cc=GB&lc=eng&nid=-536902324.536883183&pid=127539&pageMode=DS

Look through the pages for the VB example.

More general: Learn to control instruments with Visual Basic:

https://www.keysight.com/main/editorial.jspx?cc=GB&lc=eng&ckey=474107-1-eng&nid=-11143.0.00&id=474107-1-eng